# Finding the count of letters in each column

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics, biopython

I need to find the count of letters in each column as follows:

```
String: ATCG
        TGCA
        AAGC
        GCAT
```

string is a series.

I need to write a program to get the following:

```
  0 1 2 3
A 2 1 1 1
T 1 1 0 1
C 0 1 2 1
G 1 1 1 1
```

I have written the following code but I am getting a row in 0 index and column at the end (column index 450, actual column no 451) with nan values. I should not be getting either the row or the column 451. I need to have only 450 columns.

```
f = zip(*string)
counts = [{letter: column.count(letter) for letter in column} for column in 
f]
counts=pd.DataFrame(counts).transpose()
print(counts)
counts = counts.drop(counts.columns[[450]], axis =1)
```

Can anyone please help me understand the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way you can implement your logic. If required, you can turn your series into a list via `lst = s.tolist()`.

```
lst = ['ATCG', 'TGCA', 'AAGC', 'GCAT']

arr = [[i.count(x) for i in zip(*lst)] for x in ('ATCG')]

res = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=list('ATCG'))
```

**Result**

```
   0  1  2  3
A  2  1  1  1
T  1  1  0  1
C  0  1  2  1
G  1  1  1  1
```

**Explanation**

- In the list comprehension, deal with columns first by iterating the first, second, third and fourth elements of each string sequentially.
- Deal with rows second by iterating through 'ATCG' sequentially.
- This produces a list of lists which can be fed directly into `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: Tried this but getting all values as 0.

Comment: @Arpita, when you say "tried this", did you copy/paste the code *exactly as above*? The chances are either your data is different or you are not applying the above code correctly.

Comment: I did not copy paste it. I used it based on the variables in my code.

Comment: @AST, In that case, I can't help you unless you are able to provide data which demonstrates the problem. The code does work with the example data you provided in your question.

Answer (score 2):

With `Series.value_counts()`:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(['ATCG', 'TGCA', 'AAGC', 'GCAT'])

>>> s.str.join('|').str.split('|', expand=True)\
...     .apply(lambda row: row.value_counts(), axis=0)\
...     .fillna(0.)\
...     .astype(int)
   0  1  2  3
A  2  1  1  1
C  0  1  2  1
G  1  1  1  1
T  1  1  0  1
```

I'm not sure how logically you want to order the index, but you could call `.reindex()` or `.sort_index()` on this result.

The first line, `s.str.join('|').str.split('|', expand=True)` gets you an "expanded" version

```
   0  1  2  3
0  A  T  C  G
1  T  G  C  A
2  A  A  G  C
3  G  C  A  T
```

which should be faster than calling `pd.Series(list(x)) ...` on each row.